# binary tree method for array elements multiplication

Tags: c, pointers, recursion

I am trying to do a multiplication recursively. I opted for this method because it needs much less iterations than a `for` loop. The initial array is:

```
pop[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };
```

for the sake of simplicity the array values are just the indexes. The output for the first player i.e. {pop[0],pop[1]} should be:

```
resul_array[0] = pop[2]*pop[4]*pop[6]*pop[8] = 2 * 4 * 6 * 8 = 384
resul_array[1] = 2 * 4 * 6 * 9 = 432
resul_array[2] = 2 * 4 * 7 * 8 = 448
resul_array[3] = 2 * 4 * 7 * 9 = 504
resul_array[4] = 2 * 5 * 6 * 8 = 480
resul_array[5] = 2 * 5 * 6 * 9 = 540
```

and so on until

```
resul_array[15] = 3 * 5 * 7 * 9 = 945
```

My question is how to update the pointer `ptr` to achieve this pattern?

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#define NELEMS(x)  (sizeof(x) / sizeof((x)[0]))

int fun(int *ptr, int resul, int n, int pl) {
    int j, leaf;    
    ptr = ptr + 2;
    leaf = *ptr; //the elements of the tree

    printf("n=%d leaf=%d resul=%dstep=%d\n", n, leaf, resul, step);
    getchar();

    if (n == pl - 2) {
        printf("resul-final=%d\n", resul * leaf);
        return resul * leaf;
    }   
    for (j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
        resul = resul * leaf;
        n++;
        fun(ptr, resul, n, pl);     
        leaf = 1;
        ptr = ptr + 1;
        n--;
    }

    printf("Im here\n");
}

int main() {
    int pop[10] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 }; //5 players
    int resul = 1;  
    int pl = NELEMS(pop) / 2;
    int *ptr; //pointer that moves along the elements of pop
    ptr = pop;
    int *resul_array = calloc(pl, sizeof(int));

    for (i = 0; i < pl; i++) {
        resul_array[i] = fun(ptr, resul, 0, pl);
        printf("resul_array[%d]=%d\n", i, resul_array[i]);
    }
}
```

`fun(.)` uses recursion to traverse the elements of `pop`. This function uses the pointer 'ptr' to move forward two elements at a time until it reaches the returning condition i.e. `if(n==pl-2)` then `ptr` should move just one element forward.

The results Im getting are good until the third iteration which skips the `448` and instead gives `504`. I know it is because the pointer `ptr` is moving forward not according to the pattern mentioned above. Please if you can help to fix this.

I will try to depict the tree:

```
              pl
       2                3 
   4       5       4       5   
 6   7   6   7   6   7   6   7 
8 9 8 9 8 9 8 9 8 9 8 9 8 9 8 9
```

Comment: I don't understand how you are multiplying the numbers.

Comment: @Mad Physicist 'fun(.)' uses recursion to traverse the elements of 'pop'. This function uses the pointer 'ptr' to move forward two elements at a time until it reaches the returning condition then 'ptr' it should move just one element forward.

Comment: This is really unclear.  What is the pattern that dictates that `resul_array[0] = 2*4*6*8`, for example?  (Whatever it is, you should be using a debugger to help you figure out where your program's behaviour diverges from expectations...)

Comment: That pattern is what I need as an output. What I mean I need those elements of pop to be multiplied in such a way. It is not a debugging issue, as a said the logic behind the pointer is the problem.

Comment: @Arraval - If your code is not doing what you wanted, then it sounds like a debugging problem...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth thanks but believe it is not. Its a matter of logic behid how to move along the elements of `pop`.

Comment: Is that some "do it the most complicated way" contest?

Comment: I agree with you and the motivation behind it is that this procedure is part of something else which demands a lot of computation O(2^n) if I do it the "easy way" so for relatively small "n" the computational time is unfeasible.

Comment: @Arraval. Debugging is the process of figuring out why your instructions do not conform to the intended logic behind them. There is no such thing as "my code is not doing what I expected" that is not a debugging problem.

Comment: no answers, just downvotes. It is a fair interesting problem why then the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it!!!!

It takes less than a quarter the time it did with the brute force approach

Answer: `leaf = ptr[n*2+j];`

Enjoy!